# Run test script in continuous integration using CircleCI?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

We're using CircleCI for CI/CD. In the continuous integration process, I'd like to run a test script I wrote that generates some data for my app to use. Then another script will run and make sure the data was processed in a certain amount of time (performance test). Is there a way I can do this through CI/CD using CircleCI?

I have a Spark Streaming App that reads data from Kafka, processes and then puts it into a database.

I generate some data and send it to Kafka. Meanwhile, the Spark program is running (my script didn't start it I manually start it earlier). The Spark app processes this data. My script just waits about 1 minute after it initially generates the data then makes an API call to get some metrics on the data that Spark Processed, basically performance metrics.

I'd like CircleCI to take the code from Github, Build it, Deploy it to a "test" server that then runs my Spark App in the test environment which has Spark/Kafka installed. Then I'd like CircleCI to run my custom script. My script will give back some performance values in some variable say X. I'd essentially like to have CircleCI compare X against some value like `assert(X < 60)` and then I'd like CircleCI to say that this failed some test if `X < 60 == False`. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, sure. Anything you can do in a program, you can do in CircleCI. However, there is no information here about your architecture, so there isn't much more I can say other than "it is possible" `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer thank you for your response, I have updated my question with more details!

Comment: Are Kafka, Spark and your program running inside the CircleCI process? In general, it is best to arrange it so that it is self-contained, rather than reaching out to remote services. This will reduce network issues, but it also ensures you seed your systems with a fixed set of data, rather than relying on systems in an unknown/changing state.

Comment: I'm planning to have CircleCI transfer my compiled code to a test environment and run the tests there. I've thought about having circleCI run an image of the test environment, but I'm not sure how all that works with Spark since it's distributed and I need to test it in a distributed cluster

Comment: Ah right, so this is really a CD issue. Sure, you can do that - just use a private key registered with CircleCI and use that to scp a tarball to the target server and remotely uncompress. You can then start the server remotely via SSH and then run tests, either on CircleCI or via a remote script. As I said before, it would be good to have a test Spark installation so you can zap its existing data and feed it a standard seed set.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question has been asked a while ago, however if anyone has a similar requirement, [this circleci pipeline](https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/simonmittag/j8a) runs a dockerised integration and performance test against a locally deployed API server.

### Specific problems that needed solving:

1. wait for servers to start within circleci script on cli using [pwt](https://github.com/simonmittag/pwt)
2. run performance test against API using [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) with [LUA](https://github.com/simonmittag/j8a/tree/master/performance) script

### Run locally using docker (OSX)

```sh
git clone https://github.com/simonmittag/jabba.git
circleci local execute --job integration
circleci local execute --job performance
```

*Disclaimer: I'm involved with some of the linked github projects.

Comment: The first link in this answer is broken.  The answer should be edited so it provides a stand-alone solution to the problem.  Links can provide extra information, but should not be the substance of the answer.